# BizTalk Orchestration delay while communicating with external WCF Service

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

I am using a BizTalk orchestration which I use to call an external WCF web service. It is working fine for a stipulated period of time, but the call to external web services is waiting for sometime before making a call which causes a delay.

Below is the image of Orchestration Debugger.

[image: Orchestration Debugger]

As you can see that in shape "Last Seen Update Request" waiting for around 5 mins before making a call to the external WCF service.

What could be the possible cause for this delay?

Note : I am using Biztalk Server 2013 R2.

Comment: Can you give us some more details on what happens in that shape? What does this Send shape exactly do? Do you have any tracking information on the pipeline?

Comment: @PieterVandenheede : The highlighted shape is a send shape which sends out request to a WCF Service and receives a response back. We are using WCF-BasicHTTP adapter for this.

Comment: And what information is needed from the tracking information in the pipeline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As these orchestration debugger activities not documented, we can only guess that send operations indicate when "send" has started and when it finished. For SendPort to delay finish "send" operation there are several reasons:

- SendPort encounters error upon send and retry mechanism with delays kicks in;
- SendPort is using OrderedDelivery and message get queued until proceeded,
- You have no maxconnection set up in BTSNTSvc.exe.config and BizTalk strugles to make request in timely fashion using default settings (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296870%28v=bts.10%29.aspx)

Other less likely reasons might be database lockings occuring in MessageBox, preventing orchestration to publish message, but if you were having such kind of problems, you have been noticing it all along other operations.